# Weird error with MongoDb + Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am building Resteasy services with MongoDb as the database.

It works perfectly on my Mac but on Fedora 15 of the test server, it raises a error as following:

```
    07:20:15,060 WARNING [com.mongodb.tcp] (http--0.0.0.0-8000-1) Exception determining maxBSON size using0: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [eid/67.215.65.132:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:228) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:112) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:93) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:146) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:157) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.fetchMaxBsonObjectSize(DBTCPConnector.java:457) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:444) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:209) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:305) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:369) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:498) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:523) [mongo-2.7.0.jar:]
    at eid.ariel.TestService.getAllUsers(TestService.java:39) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) [:1.6.0_22]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:255) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:209) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [:1.6.0_22]
```

The code which access db is :

```
public List<DBObject> getAllUsers() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException, FileNotFoundException{
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
    DBCollection collection = mongo.getDB("eid_security_dev").getCollection("users");
    DBCursor cur = collection.find();
    List<DBObject> result = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    while (cur.hasNext()){

        result.add(cur.next());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using Mongo driver 2.7.0 and mongodb server 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [eid/67.215.65.132:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

It seems that your DB client could not connect to the MongoDB server. A few things to investigate:

- Make sure that your DB server is up and running.
- Use the `mongo` shell to verify that your MongoDB server is fully operational.
- `67.215.65.132` is a public IP address. `localhost` should normally resolve to the loopback interface with an address of `127.0.0.1` or similar. Try using `127.0.0.1` directly, since using the public IP may imply the existence of firewall rules that block access to the DB server port. The connection timing out instead of being refused make this scenario quite probable.

Comment: DB is up and running, mongo shell is working fine, 127.0.0.1 gives me the same result. I don't know where 67.215.65.132 comes from :(

Comment: The error just disappears after I re-install the whole server and use 127.0.0.1 this time.... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://forums.opendns.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=2860).  For example, you are using OpenDNS which returns this IP for unknown host.